# If I have a single word as my official name since birth then what should I fill in as the second name in the GRE form?

Tags: masters, gre, personal-name

I have just a single name "Anubhav" in every one of my official documents, be it my passport, my official birth certificate, my secondary education certificate, my senior secondary certificate etc. What should I fill in as my second name in the GRE form?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but perhaps the safest solution would be to [contact ETS](https://www.ets.org/gre/contact) and ask (and please write an answer here if you find a solution! It would be very helpful for future readers).

Comment: Do you mean a middle name (in Western convention)? I ask since you appear to be using a second name in your user name.

Comment: @Jon Custer , the second name in my username is not official, I have a first name only

Comment: OK, I was a bit confused there. For some places, one uses things like NMN (No Middle Name) or NMI (No Middle Initial) and NLN (No Last Name). For GRE you would have to ask (and there may well be a FAQ somewhere on ETS' site).

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-would-you-fill-GRE-form-if-you-do-not-have-a-surname-in-passport may help

Comment: I know of a couple of cases where a person with only a single name put it in both the "first name" and "last name" fields of some forms. But I don't know whether ETS approves of that.